# C# regex performance with whitespace is too slow

Tags: regex, search, .net-2.0, whitespace, performance

I'm using WinForms NET 2.0 in C#.

I have text files, of about 1000-1500 lines. Certain lines in them begin with 4 or more letter words and I have to add a colon to these words. Having whitespace at the beginning of these lines is optional, and the line can contain more text apart from those words. Here's an example:

```
    lda $00,x
    mov $20
    rep #$20
    tax
    lda #$0000,y
word
    ...         ; comment
  anotherword           ; this word has whitespace before it.
```

Also, if there already is a colon, it simply ignores them to prevent more from being added. Here is my code:

```
Regex R = new Regex(@"^\s*(?<word>[A-Za-z0-9_]{4,})", RegexOptions.Multiline); //keep the words stored in a group called word
MatchCollection M = R.Matches(txt); //let my text file string be "txt"

foreach (Match m in M)
{
    string mm = m.Groups["word"].Value;
    if (!Regex.IsMatch(txt, @"^\s*\b" + mm + @"\b:", RegexOptions.Multiline)) // if already a colon, return
        txt = Regex.Replace(txt, @"^\s*\b" + mm + @"\b", mm + ":", RegexOptions.Multiline);
}
```

It works and all, but the problem? It's far too slow. I do other operations in the text file, but I've confirmed they are quick and the problem lies in the two "\s*"'s in my regex above. When I remove them both, the search becomes 10x faster.

How could I fix this?

Comment: Parsing a very large string with a multi-line regex is going to be slow.  Why not read the text file line by line and apply the regex iteratively? I would at least try this and compare the speed -- it may in fact be faster.  For example, from my own experiments, I have found that having 2 separate regexes is generally faster than 1 regex with alternation ("or" operator `|`).

Comment: @bobbymcr: Hmm, I should have thought about that before. I'll give it a try and then see the results.

Comment: @zneak: What I am doing is 6502 assembly yeah, but this is just some random code thrown in just to make an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternate solution to @TimPietzcker's:

```
result = Regex.Replace(subject, @"^(?>(\s*\w{4,}))(?!:)", "$1:", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

where `(?>...)` is an atomic grouping. When the regex engine enters an atomic grouping, it is not allowed to backtrack anywhere in the input this grouping has consumed.

Now, why is this benefical? Consider a line:

```
             ab3 #13 spaces, then a, b, 3
```

If you do not use an atomic grouping, when the regex fails to match the 4th character in the second quantifier, it must backtrack to the character before `a`: but it is a space, it doesn't match. And so on until it reaches the character before the beginning of a line, where `^` doesn't match, only then declaring a failure (`\s*` can match an empty string).

With an atomic grouping, the engine will not backtrack this way, which is a huge gain of performance, especially when you deal with large data.

Comment: Yes, the possessive/atomic mods may improve efficiency a bit, but a much bigger improvement of this expression over Tim's is the: `^` anchor at the start. This reduces the number of locations where the engine attempts each match (assuming .NET implements the: _"Start of string/line optimization"_ - See:  [MRE3](http://www.amazon.com/Mastering-Regular-Expressions-Jeffrey-Friedl/dp/0596528124 "Mastering Regular Expressions (3rd Edition)") chapter 6 page 246). However, .NET may be smart enough to apply this optimization for Tim's expression as well (but I kind of doubt it.) +1.

Comment: It would have to be atomic groups in this case; .NET doesn't support possessive quantifiers.

Comment: @AlanMoore really? I thought it did in the latest versions

Comment: Not as of [.NET 4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=VS.110%29.aspx#quantifiers).  It's always bugged me, too; possessive quantifiers are *so* much more convenient.

Comment: There is so much in Regex which I did not know! I will probably learn about it in detail. On another note, how would I add "exceptions" to this? For example, there's about 50 4-letter words which may start the beginning of lines, and I do not want to append a colon to those.

Comment: @david you certainly don't want to use a regex with 50+ exceptions in it. Make a list with keywords you don't want, capture the keyword, compare: if no match, only then do the replacement. This means you need to make the group start after `\s*` in the regex.

Answer (score 2):

I see three major problems here:

1. You're performing essentially the same regex match as many as three times on every line.  As Tim demonstrated, you shouldn't have to touch any line more than once, whether it matches the regex or not.  Also, you should never need to test a string with Match() or IsMatch() before executing a Replace() with the same regex.  If the string doesn't match the regex, Replace() will simply return it unchanged.
2. There's no need to build the replacement string my hand as you're doing now.  That's what capturing groups are for.
3. `\s` matches all whitespace characters, which includes newlines.  If there are (for example) nine blank lines followed by a matching line, the regex will consume all ten lines.  If the tenth line *doesn't match, the regex engine will abandon that match attempt and try again starting at the second blank line.  And again at the third line, the fourth line, etc..  If removing the `\s*` from your regex had a big effect, this is probably the reason: it's trying to match a lot of whitespace unnecessarily.  If you know the strings you're looking for will always be on a single line, you should make sure the regex matches only *horizontal* whitespace--i.e., spaces and tabs.

To demonstrate:

```
result = Regex.Replace(subject, @"(?m)^([ \t]*\w{4,})(?![\w:])", "$1:");
```

To explain:

- `(?m)` is merely a more convenient way to specify the Multiline option.
- `^([ \t]*\w{4,})` matches the first word on the line along with any leading whitespace, and captures it all in group #1.
- `(?![\w:])` is a negative lookahead; it asserts that the next character (if there is one) is neither a word character nor a colon.  This insures that you've consumed the whole word, and the word isn't followed by a colon.
- In the replacement argument, `$1` is a placeholder for the contents of the first capturing group.

I noticed that your regex matches the leading whitespace without capturing it, and you don't add any in the replacement.  The effect is to remove the leading whitespace from any line you perform this replacement on, but not from any other lines.  If that's really what you want, you can change `^([ \t]*\w{4,})` to `^[ \t]*(\w{4,})`.

Comment: I never thought of using [ \t] instead of \s (nor did I think of \s checking for newlines), thanks for that and all of the tips.